# Run Selenium on Windows and MacOS devices without installing software?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to run a Selenium script on a device without installing software or browser extension?

The aim is to screen share with the user of the remote device. They will be running as a standard user without the privileges required to install software, they will also not be allowed to install anything else such as browser extensions. The script should open a browser and go to a URL. The mouse should then make a series of clicks on the application. Ideally this would also be recorded within the script itself and accessible from the cloud server, worst case is it would be saved locally.

Perhaps Selenium isn’t the answer, any suggestions are more than welcome.

I have been able to use BrowserStack to record a script and then run on my device, but I had to install software on my device to do so.